# android questionnaire activity

Tags: android

I am currently looking to create an application in Android where a user can answer a questionnaire and that information is saved. The questionnaire will be in a sqlite database and can have different set on answers, and their can be several questionnaires the user can choose to fill. how do i go about firstly having the ability to create a dynamic questionnaire view for the user?

Comment: I want the app to be able to function without the internet so a web view is not ideal. The questions do not need to be in random order. The questionnaire will be in a question database, and then one question can have different types of answers, so for example i would try show this in a spinner, or radio/checkbox. Then i need to save the answer into a table, there could be several different questionnaires and answers etc. i hope i am explaining it correctly. i havent created a dynamic activity in android before..please if anyone could provide useful code thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you have gone through some of the Android tutorials. Here are some tips (Not sure if this helps). Strongly suggest to go through some Android tutorials.

You need an [activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) that will connect to a database [cursor](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db). To display the layout options you could use some smarts as described in [layout tricks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html) [I made an assumption that you want to reuse the layouts]. You could add some smarts in your Activity code to the answer_display_type (i.e. the widget required to show the answer) and could hide/display parts of layout.

Comment: I have gone through some tutorials and i know how to get data out into a cursor. The issue is the questionnaire will be downloaded from a server to the database, and the questions answer types etc. could be different so i cant pre-define the layout.

Comment: Yep. That is fine. When you download the questions and answers, include extra columns for answer_display_type/widget .. You can run a switch case inside your activity to check this and accordingly hide/unhide and populate your layout objects. Effectively you will have one layout that will contain an area for question and all types of widgets for answers.(Spinner, checkbox, radio etc). This will simplify your activity code ... just to make it hide/unhide for the current record from cursor.

Comment: Sounds like what I need, would you be able to provide some code to make it easier for me to understand and how it all comes together. Also im not sure how the answer will be affected and managed correctly

Comment: Dont think I have time to write code. You could see the layouttricks for some ideas for layout. The code in Activity will be similar to what you for swing UI (Presume you are familiar to Java). Go through some tutorials from developer.android.com